# VBA for Sorting on protected WS

Tags: excel, vba, macos, macos-sierra

Hi I have searched a lot to find a possible workaround to be able to sort (not filter) a table on a protected worksheet. NOTE: also if you protect a sheet and allow sorting (AllowSorting:=True somewhere in the code) it is not possible to sort locked cells.

The cells need to stay locked and the workbook protected.

My approach so far is to use a Workbook_change event code that unprotects the workbook, when the HEADERROW of the table is selected (where the filter/sorting button is) - and protects the workbook for any other selection. (Note: Locked cells and unlocked cells are treated equally (as unlocked) when a worksheet is unprotected)

This is the code I am trying to run(on MAC Excel 2016) where I need help.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim Ws As Worksheet
    If (Target.Row = 11) Then    'Row 11 is the tables header's row
       With Ws
       .Unprotect ""
       End With
    Else
        With Ws
        .Protect "", UserInterfaceonly:=True
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

The protection has no password. What am I doing wrong?
Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: You have not set your Ws variable to anything. You could use Target.Worksheet instead of Ws or do Set Ws = Target.Worksheet

Comment: Thanks for your comment.

It is a private sub, so it already is dedicated to one specific worksheet. But yes I can do that. Unfortunately does not solve the coding problem.

Comment: Your Ws variable will not be set to the containing worksheet automatically.

Comment: What exactly IS your coding problem? What is the error message? What happes/does not happen?

Comment: Just rechecked and actually makes the code run fine. Thanks a lot!!!

Now I tried it out a bit and what I need to get solved is not to get an VBA error when selecting the target cells (headerrow, row 11) and other cells together. 

So right now selecting cells in the tablebodyrange and then clicking on the headerrow to filter creates a VB Error: 
"Run-time error '1004':

Method 'Unprotect' of object '_Worksheet' failed"

Any Idea how to make the code "user-safer" and avoid this error?

The user should not notice there is VBA running and not get interrupted